# ellipsis disappeared when UILabel or UITextView has empty line

Tags: ios, uilabel, uitextview

When I tried to use UILabel to set a label with `numberOfLines = 3` , a problem came to me. Once there are any empty lines, the ellipsis will never show up.
Normally, when we set a string like `abc\ndef\nghi\njkl`, we get this:

```
abc
def
ghi...
```

And if the string is like `\nabc\ndef\nghi\njkl`, it will be :

```
abc
def
```

**The ellipsis just disappered!**

This problem is in UILabel and UITextView.

Anyone know how to deal with this problem?

Comment: Seems like a bug. You could strip leading whitespace from the string.

Comment: Very likely a bug. One "work around" ... check if first char is `"\n"` and prepend a space: `" \n"`

Comment: @HangarRash yeah, I think it's a bug too. As for `strip leading whitespace`, I don't think it's a good solution. Because sometimes we will need to show the empty line。What i did to solve the problem is to add whitespace before `\n`.

Comment: @DonMag That's what I have done. It really work and didn't change the interface. But still, it's not a good way. We just make it work but we didn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My solution is to add a space before '\n'. And since the empty line is nomore an empty line, the ellipsis shows again. But still, we didn't solve this problem in system way. It's not a good way for it. I wonder if there is a way to solve it with system method.